# Need help to create a Koch Snowflake of numbers in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, fractals

I want to write a function in python that will take an initial string ('F' for example) and replace every 'F' with 'F-F++f-f', then will repeat. So the parameters of the function would be a number telling the function how many times it should do this.

I haven't wrote any code because I'm not sure where to start but I think I would need to use the while loop to make it repeat.

Examples:

```
snowflake(1)
#It would return
'F'
snowflake(2)
#It would return
'F-F++F-F'
snowflake(3)
#It would return
''F-F++F-F-F-F++F-F++F-F++F-F-F-F++F-F'
```

And so on, how should I do this?

Comment: You've only included `F` as an example, so what happens with other input? You should show what you've tried/researched and take a look at [ask]

Comment: Well the parameter, or input would be a number. That would tell the function how many times it wants to repeat to make the fractal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a normal `for` loop:

```
def snowflake(x):
    s = 'F'
    for i in range(x-1):
        s = s.replace('F', 'F-F++F-F')
    return s
```

which when run, will output:

```
>>> snowflake(1)
'F'
>>> snowflake(2)
'F-F++F-F'
>>> snowflake(3)
'F-F++F-F-F-F++F-F++F-F++F-F-F-F++F-F'
```

Comment: thank you! This works perfectly, is there a way to also make it work for the Hilbert Curve? The Hilbert would be you start with L, L becomes "+RF-LFL-FR+", then 'R' becomes '-LF+RFR+FL-'.

Comment: @KittyWhale, You are welcome. Could you post this as a new question, because this original question's already answered? You can also protect your question from downvotes, if you produce some code that you tried next time. Good luck!

Comment: Okkk I will, I just really wasn't sure how to start but you made it look really easy lol.

Comment: Now that you got a start, try yourselves to solve the rest. When stuck, ping a question with your code. :)

Comment: I posted the new question

Answer (score 2):

This can be implemented using a recursive function. For example you can define

```
def snowflake(in_str, n):
    if n == 1:
        return in_str
    else:
        return snowflake(in_str.replace('F', 'F-F++F-F'), n-1)
```

where `in_str` is your input and `n` is the number of times that you need this function applied to `in_str`

You have then for example

```
print(snowflake('F', 3))
'F-F++F-F-F-F++F-F++F-F++F-F-F-F++F-F'
```